# How do I generate a new static page in an existing PagesController in rails to have all invokes rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I add a new static page in an existing Pages Controller.
Here is an About and Home Pages. 
I did

```
rails generate controller Pages start
```

to add a Page which names Start, but there is an error message

```
conflict  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
```

I don't install manually because when I do it, the import scss vendor is not called. And I write al my css code in /home.scss Have you the syntax to type it in the console?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't do this via the console.

To add the new action to the controller do the following steps:

Add `start` action to your `PagesController`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def start
  end

  # your existing code.
end
```

Then create a view `app/views/pages/start.html.erb`

Then add route to your action. Edit your `config/routes.rb`:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/start' => 'pages#start'
end
```

Actually I don't know what is your current `routes.rb` content and your goals. But it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you but the scss vendor import doesn't work when I do it manually.

Comment: Yes I do that but I didn't work. There is an error in my layout with this line : {<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>}

Comment: I'd like to get more info to investigate it. It there a link to your repo?

Comment: Yes but where do I put my scss code to style my view start